# Break while loop every 3 iterations

Tags: php, html, css

I am using this PHP to generate a list from 0-9.

```
$counter = 0; 
WHILE ($counter < 10) 
{ 
  print "counter is now " . $counter . "<br>"; 
  $counter++; 
}
```

I'd like to change how this works. Every **3rd iteration**, I'd like to wrap my printed text in a `<div>` if possible.

So eventually my outputted code would be:

```
<div>
counter is now 0
counter is now 1
counter is now 2
</div>
<div>
counter is now 3
counter is now 4
counter is now 5
</div>
<div>
counter is now 6
counter is now 7
counter is now 8
</div>
<div>
counter is now 9
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With modulus operator you can split your output every 3 iterations but you still need to check for `limit` values that could generate empty `div` blocks

```
<?php

$counter = 0; 
$limit = 10;

print "<div>\n";

while ($counter < $limit) { 
  print "counter is now " . $counter . "<br>\n"; 

  if (++$counter % 3 === 0 && $counter < $limit) {
    print "</div>\n<div>\n";

  }
}
print "</div>\n";
```

Comment: You don't need `&& $counter < $limit` in your if statement since it's a condition for being in the loop. I would also use echo instead of print.

Comment: @Pierre-EmmanuelLevesque try the code on http://writecodeonline.com/php/ , change `$limit = 9` and remove `&& $counter < $limit`as you say: an empty div will be generated at the bottom.

Comment: Ah! Just realized the counter is incremented in the same line. My bad. I need to drink some coffee I think.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [modulus](http://php.net/language.operators.arithmetic) to do it

```
while($counter < 10) {
   if($counter % 3 == 0) {
       //Do something for the third row
   }
   $counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$counter = 0;
$block_count = 0;
echo "<div>";
while ($counter < 10) {
if ($block_count === 3) {
    echo "</div><div>";
    $block_count = 0;
}
  echo "counter is now " . $counter . "<br>";
  $block_count++;
  $counter++; 
}
echo "</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know php but i think the logic is the same :

```
$counter2 =0; //count to 10
$stopIteration =10;

WHILE($counter2<$stopIteration){ 
    print "<div>";
    $counter1 =0; //count to 3
    WHILE($counter1<3){
        print "counter is now".$counter2."<br>";
        $counter1++;
        $counter2++;
    }
    print "</div>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that best failsafe approach for this kind of task would be group all data (in this case all 10 your printed strings) in array, than split this array in chunks http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php, and then you can work with this new array, because it is divided in chunks, where each chunk is not greater than for example 3. but your output won't fail because modals will only work if your total count of elements modal is 0, in this case 10 elements will fail, because in last loop modal statement won't work.

this will add failsafe when there isn't total elements that divides with 3.

```
$counter = 0; 
$arr = array();
WHILE ($counter < 10) 
{ 
  $arr[] =  "counter is now " . $counter . "<br>"; 
  $counter++; 
}

$arr = array_chunk($arr, 3);
foreach ($arr as $chunk) {
    //wrap each chunk into div
    echo "<div>"
    foreach ($chunk as $string) {
        //print your string here
     }
    echo "</div>"
}
```